# Trying to use a variable that is inside a function for different functions?

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x

I am having trouble with a certain part of my code. So basically I'm writing a program about stocks and downloading the prices/dates from the internet, and am having trouble using the list date, which has everything from the webpage in one list, and want to use the variable date in other functions but when I try, it says date does not exist. Basically I can't call date outside of the function. Can anyone help me please?

P.S. The goal that I'm trying to reach is to use the variable date in other functions such as ones that pluck out each date in the list date and put them into one list, and pluck each closing price from the list date and put them into one list.

```
def _print_url_contents(response: http.client.HTTPResponse) -> None:
    content_bytes = response.read()
    content_string = content_bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8')
    content_lines = content_string.splitlines()

    print()
    date = []

    for line in content_lines:
        date.append(line)
    return date
```

Comment: This isn't Jython or some other variant, is it? Reason I ask is that `-> None` is not vanilla Python.

Comment: It's Python 3.  It's normal python.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy It's Python3, and `->` notation is called [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

Comment: @LeonardYi Please add the tag python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the return value to some variable?  If yes, that's how you should access date.  BTW, why are you annotating that you're returning None, when really you're returning a list of date strings?

I thought Python 3 type annotations were advisory only, nonbinding.  But it still concerns me a little to see a type annotation that's clearly out of sync with reality.

Comment: Yea I forgot to change the None my bad! Also when I type in _print_url_contents.date, it says that the variable is not found

Answer (score 0):

You can return more than one variable and you can send in more than one variable. So just return all the variables you want to access from the print function to the driver function.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't access `date` - it would be terrible if you could! (see the concepts of scope for further explanations).

A possible work around would be to define `date` gloabally (poutside your function) and use 
`global date` inside your function if needed.

The other option would be returning `date` and passing it to the next function

Third option would be to define a dedicated object which exists only once (see "singleton") which keeps the date. But still you'll have to know how to access it (for possible solutions see above)...